# MATLAB, multiple equality 'shortcut'

Tags: matlab

I have the following array:

```
a = magic(12);
a = a(:,1);
```

It's a list of these twelve numbers:

```
144
 13
 25
108
 96
 61
 73
 60
 48
109
121
 12
```

Now if I want to 'filter out' the values of 25, 61 and 109, I could write something like this:

```
m = (a == 25) | (a == 61) | (a == 109)
```

However, is there a way to write that more easily? Something like:

```
m = a IN(25, 61, 109)
```

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = ismember(a, [25 61 109]);
```

docs for [ismember here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html).